# Applescript Error

Tags: applescript

We are trying to install an app thru Applescript using terminal commands as mentioned below. Firstly it will mount the dmg file and then install the app to App folder.
While installing app to App folder its asking for password, how to handle this password using Applescript??

```
hdiutil mount /Users/rajasekaranr/Downloads/install_flash_player_osx.dmg"
sudo cp -R "/Volumes/Flash Player 2/Install Adobe Flash Player.app" /Applications
```

Error while executing the above commands using apple script

```
error "sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified" number 1
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Executing Terminal command programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12312130/executing-terminal-command-programmatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
property usr : "username"
property pswd : "password"

set fromPath to quoted form of "/Volumes/Flash Player 2/Install Adobe Flash Player.app"
set toPath to quoted form of "/Applications"
do shell script "cp -R " & fromPath & space & toPath user name usr password pswd with administrator privileges
```

Comment: can you pls tell me how to implement the below command also -store -pkg "/Volumes/AdbeRdr1014_en_US 1/Adobe Reader X Installer.pkg" -target /. I tried with the above steps but its not working for the above command